# XCDYouTubeClient Not playing Video in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, youtube-api, swift4

I am trying to play youtube videos by `XCDYouTubeClient` library but it not play the video.I also refer the documentation but it didn't help me to resolve issue

```
let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
self.present(playerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

XCDYouTubeClient.default().getVideoWithIdentifier("tG7vx7-3sl0") { [weak playerViewController] (video: XCDYouTubeVideo?, error: Error?) in
      if let streamURLs = video?.streamURLs, let streamURL = (streamURLs[XCDYouTubeVideoQualityHTTPLiveStreaming] ?? streamURLs[XCDYouTubeVideoQuality.HD720] ?? streamURLs[XCDYouTubeVideoQuality.medium360] ?? streamURLs[XCDYouTubeVideoQuality.small240]) {
           playerViewController?.player = AVPlayer(url: streamURL)
      } else {
           self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
       }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code. Some of youtube link not having  `XCDYouTubeVideoQuality.HD720` video quality. Just remove it and video start to play.

```
XCDYouTubeClient.default().getVideoWithIdentifier("tG7vx7-3sl0") { [weak self] (video, error) in

   if video != nil {
     var streamURLs = video?.streamURLs
     let streamURL = streamURLs?[XCDYouTubeVideoQualityHTTPLiveStreaming] ?? streamURLs?[NSNumber(value: XCDYouTubeVideoQuality.medium360.rawValue)] ?? streamURLs?[NSNumber(value: XCDYouTubeVideoQuality.small240.rawValue)]
     if let streamURL = streamURL {
         playerViewController?.player = AVPlayer(url: streamURL)
     }
     playerViewController?.player?.play()

   } else {
      self?.dismiss(animated: true)
   } 
}
```

Comment: This is not the correct answer. `XCDYouTubeVideoQuality.HD720` not being available will not make a difference as OP is using optional unwrapping.